# which web site tracking tool do not have Report Data Sampling

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking

Which web site tracking tools do not have Report Data Sampling?

Currently, I'm using Google Analytics; however, due to my business requirements, the report dimension will contains many combinations, resulting in Google Analytics limiting data due to report sampling. As a result, it would make the business report not accurate enough

I've heard that Yahoo Web Analytics does not have Data Sampling, and leaves the option to user to view raw data as well, and that it supports a longer history too...

Comment: This question belongs on Webmasters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On free version of GA
The pageview limit by default is set to 5 million per month

But it can be unlimited while you apply a account on google adwords and contact their sale, and buy at least one adwords to active the account, beware that the account register email should same as GA

Since different country has different approach, above one is for Hong Kong..not sure is only approach or..